# XML parsing images URL inside content

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I already have XML parsing set up. I want to parse the images, but they are inside the content:encoded branch in XML, inside HTML img tag. Like this:

```
<p>Sometext...</p> <p><img class="alignnone" src="https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10407774_10152942478477367_248202413385136381_n.jpg?oh=ea41869809b276243d5dab98338fcb6d&amp;oe=552CA121" alt="" width="600" height="450" /></p>
```

I want to parse the image. Is it possible, if someone could provide me some code? Here's my **XMLParser.java**: http://laravel.io/bin/d9X3v
My **GetArticles.java**: http://laravel.io/bin/Kkq4q
And **MainActivity.java**: http://laravel.io/bin/xKWwQ

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you want is the SRC or source of the Image.

Here is a simple test of how we can get the SRC from the XML document (properly formatted) by the way:

```
    // Added parent tag "doc" to hold the data
    Document doc = getDomElement("<doc><p>Sometext...</p> <p><img class=\"alignnone\" src=\"https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10407774_10152942478477367_248202413385136381_n.jpg?oh=ea41869809b276243d5dab98338fcb6d&amp;oe=552CA121\" alt=\"\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" /></p></doc>");
    // get list of all img tags
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
    // go through the list of img tags and get the source
    for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
        Node n = nList.item(i);
        System.out.println("image src: " + n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src"));
    }
```